# python data structure for certain networks, breadth first search

Tags: python, networking, bioinformatics, breadth-first-search, feedback

The title may be  little unclear, but to give a brief explanation, I'm applying some biological networks like protein networks to programming. I want to use a breadth-first search to calculate some values. Here's an example of a network I'm currently working with:
[image: sample network]

*On a side note, just because a node isn't named doesn't mean its not a node. Just means its name is not significant for the network.*

Simpler example:
[image: Simple Network]

My problem here is that I need to represent this network with a data structure, which I need to use to calculate 2 values for every node:

- The # of signal paths for a node (how many paths there are from input to output that includes the node)
- The # of feedback loops for a node (how many loop paths the node is in)

I need to calculate these values for **every** single node in the network. Python came to mind because it's a standard for bioinformatics, but I'm open to other languages with potentially built in structures. Within Python, the only thing that comes to mind is some form of DFA/dictionary sort of deal to represent these kind of networks, but I'm posting the question here to see if anyone else has a better idea.

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/

Comment: I've spent some time looking through it, and there doesn't seem to be a way to use the structure to calculate what I want, which is the paths and feedback loops for each node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkX works well. If you read section 4.39.2 of the [documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/networkx/stable/networkx.pdf), you will see how to do BFS with NetworkX